# Where is the insert key on a MacBook Air?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I am trying to edit a line of code within a program that I use for work.

I need to use the <kbd>insert</kbd> key to be able to add additional spaces that I can then type letters, numbers or characters.

How to get this function to work on my MacBook Air?

Comment: What program are you using on your MBA that requires an insert key?  In that program are you certain that the Insert key will do what you expect on your MBA? Try plugging in a PC-style USB keyboard and pressing Insert in the program; does it work as expected?

Comment: What country / language keyboard are you using?

Comment: Related: [Simulate INSERT key in Mac OS X](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/169130/22781)

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> = <kbd>Insert</kbd>

(MacBook Air 13)

Also Works on MacBook Pro.

Comment: fn-return is normally enter.

Comment: This actually worked for me, also MBA 2013.  Upvote.

Comment: This worked for me on an MBA 2013, running Windows

Comment: Same here on an MBA 2013 using ArchLinux.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked for me on a 2012 Macbook Pro on Windows 10 (via Bootcamp).

Comment: doesn't work for me, Sierra, Macbook pro 2014 retina

Answer (score 17):

I need the insert key in the Midnight Commander (MC) running in Terminal and in Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) when connecting to my Windows PC.

For Midnight Commander the answer is Ctrl+T.

For RDP I did not find better solution than to use a free program on Windows [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and map the key to chosen key combination, for instance this macro maps the Insert key to Ctrl+Alt+I :

**^!i::**
**Send {INSERT}**

Answer found on [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/rdc-for-mac-how-to-do-insert-key-to-go-into-insert/ae0eab7d-7066-41a7-a9a6-7755ff983ac8?msgId=dd979e92-a753-4d92-8e84-cb565c977583&tab=AllReplies#tabs)

Comment: Please don't accept this bug and complain on https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5296f0ac-2ccd-45a7-b722-3d5e46bd475c/microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac-insert-key?forum=winRDc -- that's the only way to get the needed attention and have it fixed!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the physical keyboard and on the keyboard layout. You can try...

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
OR 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>

Comment: Finally, something that worked. CTRL+FN+M worked on my MacBook Pro (4,1). Everything else failed.

Comment: Nah... fails on my Macbook 2015 with Catalina..... Come on Apple, for petessakes !!!!

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> works for me to insert.

Comment: Your answer here is merely a repeat of an existing answer.  In addition to posting a short confirmation, be sure to mark up the existing answer that you agree with.

Comment: Worked for me, MBA 2013

Comment: Not always... not for on my Macbook 2015 with Catalina - it merely insert a new line.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a possible answer to this question in a similar question topic on StackExchange:

[How do I simulate the Insert key in Windows on a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/how-do-i-simulate-the-insert-key-in-windows-on-a-macbook-pro/169370#169370)

In it, I'm explaining how to re-map the key combination `Fn+Ctrl` to `Insert` using [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/).

Answer (score 0):

On the latest Macbook Air 13" <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> works.