# Insert key on keyboard for Macbook Air Mountain Lion OS

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Air running the "Mountain Lion" OS that is version 10.8 -

What is the "Insert key" (Ins) or equivalent on Mac keyboard. ?

Answer (score 3):

An external keyboard or on screen keyboard with numpad is required.

See page 4 here > http://na.sage.com/sage-300-erp/sage-300-erp-online/~/media/site/sage-300-erp/assets/online/Sage-300-ERP-Online-Mac-Resource-Guide.pdf

Mac keyboards lack the Insert key which is used in Sage 300 ERP for adding new lines to lists.

So instead, if using a Mac, on a keyboard with a number pad, with Numlock OFF, the “0” button will act as the Insert key.

Answer (score 2):

try fn+enter.  Don't you hate it when you ask how to do something and people answer "why would you want to do that?"

Comment: Nobody asked "why" he wanted to do that, rather it was stated that the function he appeared to be requesting is not something that exists on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since we clarified that you are looking for insert keyboard key as function, it does not exist on Apple keyboards.

To insert text, you can simply highlight the text and typing will replace it (insert).

To insert a line, just use the return key at the end of the previous line.

*MS office products have an Insert function. As long as we do not know your accounting software, we can not give you a more precise answer.*