# The Insert key without 3rd party apps on MacBook Air in VirtualBox running Linux

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, copy-paste, virtualbox, x11

### Hardware setup

I use MacBook Air with what seems to be an English international keyboard layout. My Input Sources are set to *Polish - Pro* in the Keyboard settings.

[image: English international keyboard layout MacBook Air]

### Software setup

I run Debian 8.6.0 in a VirtualBox with a dwm window manager and xterm as the default terminal app there. The way copy and pasting works there is to select the text and press either *Insert* or the middle mouse bottom to paste the selection elsewhere.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to simulate pressing either of them. Is there a way to do it on MacBook Air with any 3rd party apps to remap my keyboard? I'm just looking for a way to copy and paste text in Debian Linux running inside the VirtualBox.

Here's what I've tried so far:

#### Insert key:

- <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>
- <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> (*prints `m` obviously*)
- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> (*prints `5~`*)
- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> (*prints `6~`*)
- <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> (*prints `i` obviously*)

Neither of which work.

#### Middle mouse button:

- Press the touchpad with two fingers simultaneously.
- Press the touchpad with two fingers simultaneously holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Neither of which work.

#### References:

- [Where is the insert key on a MacBook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29463/where-is-the-insert-key-on-a-macbook-air)
- [How do I simulate the Insert key in Windows on a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/how-do-i-simulate-the-insert-key-in-windows-on-a-macbook-pro)
- [Insert key on keyboard for Macbook Air Mountain Lion OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95421/insert-key-on-keyboard-for-macbook-air-mountain-lion-os?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It is not what I am looking for but it is a fine solution for the time being. If someone suggests a way to simulate the Insert key on MacBook Air I'll be happy to accept their answer.*

#### A workaround in the Debian Linux itself

If you run `xev` to see what keycodes are actually being sent when you press keys you'll probably notice that <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> produces `keycode 104 KP_Enter` instead of `keycode 36 Return`.

I decided to remap `keycode 104` to Insert with `xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = Insert"`.

As a result I am able to paste with <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### References

- [Missing Apple MacBook Keys: How to map the INSERT key in Linux/VirtualBox](https://objectorientedsoftwareconstruction.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/missing-apple-macbook-keys-how-to-map-the-insert-key-in-linuxvirtualbox/)
- [xmodmap on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)
- [Remap the insert key](https://www.flyn.org/notes/insert/index.html)