# How to remap a key to another letter

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

My "e" key is broken and until I go to repair it I would like to map the letter "e" to another key such as "§" so that I don't have to store the letter in the clipboard. What is a good solution for Catalina/Big Sur that does not involve 3rd party apps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of INS key: no key combination whatsoever works on my MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275640/equivalent-of-ins-key-no-key-combination-whatsoever-works-on-my-macbook)

Comment: Also, see this duplicate answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323375/119271