# Simulate INSERT key in Mac OS X

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

Long story short, I am using Citrix to remote into my PC at work, and several applications require the use of the INSERT key, which, as everyone knows, Apple chose to eliminate from their keyboards. I've tried everything I can think of, and never been able to find an easy way to send this keycode via Citrix.  I'm sure there are other uses for this, and I've read quite a few people's questions on the subject, but no one seems to have offered a viable solution.

I have the Apple USB keyboard (full-size, with numeric keypad), and in the position where the INSERT key would normally exist, Apple placed the "fn" key. Now, I still need this key from time to time, but what I'd love to see is perhaps Control-fn or similar to send the keycode for INSERT.  If anyone knows how to achieve this, preferably without installing 3rd-party software (adware?), I'm all ears.

Comment: There's a great thread at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/how-do-i-simulate-the-insert-key-in-windows-on-a-macbook-pro/

Answer (score 39):

For Midnight commander it seem to be <kbd>^/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>=<kbd>Insert</kbd>. As suggested by jherran.

The more generic Insert function is supposed to be <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return/Enter</kbd>=<kbd>Insert</kbd>, [see this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29463/where-is-the-insert-key-on-a-macbook-air) for more discussion and details.

I have however had little success with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> working reliably in many applications.

Comment: Thanks, but no, that doesn't seem to work for me, either.  As I mentioned above, I'm actually using Citrix, but it should be a fairly generic key-mapping. If one doesn't exist, I'd appreciate knowing how to create a custom key binding.

Comment: It does not work in LibreOffice for Mac

Comment: Ctrl+T works for me

Answer (score 6):

You can follow [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/169370/22781) which suggesting to use [Karabiner app](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to simulate *Insert* key with the following configuration of [`private.xml` file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) (edit in *Misc* tab):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Fn + Ctrl-Left to Insert</name>
    <identifier>private.fn_ctrl_to_insert</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::FN,
      KeyCode::PC_INSERT
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

and then enable newly created item after reloading the file in *Change Key* tab.

To find out the right key code, use *EventViewer* in *Misc* tab.

---

For Karabiner Element [11.1+](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/releasenotes/), they've changed the config file to `karabiner.json`, so the modifications would become:

```json
{
    "profiles": [
        {
            "complex_modifications": {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "description": "Fn + Ctrl-Left to Insert",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "left_control",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "fn"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "insert"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See also the [doc](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/from/) for the available keys and the semantic for the modifiers.

Answer (score 6):

fn + i worked for me and it enabled insert on my latest mac book pro terminal.

Comment: This was the solution for me on MACOSX High Sierra

Answer (score 5):

In iTerm2, you can remap any key under Preferences... -> Profiles -> Keys -> +. For the insert key, select as Action "Send Escape Sequence" and as value `ESC + [2~`.

On my keyboard, pressing the Insert key appears to trigger the "Help" action, so this is what I remap. This works for instance for Midnight Commander.

[image: Remaping Insert in iTerm2]

Alternatively, you can try to edit `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and insert a line like

```
"\UF727" = insertText:;
```

(See [NSEvent.h](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSEvent.h#L436) for the left-hand side and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding/3005223-inserttext?language=objc) for the right-hand side of this setting.)

Answer (score 4):

I use Citrix and I have the same issue, can't figure it out. only thing I found is if you have the external keypad, press clear to turn numlock off, then press 0 and it works as insert

Answer (score 3):

The only combination I have found is Ctrl + A.

Edit: macOS Sierra

Answer (score 2):

Get non-apple external keyboad.

Comment: Downvoted into oblivion, but yes, this is probably the most generic - if not all to obvious - solution to this problem. In case all else fails, get another keyboard.

Comment: This is great advice, but in 2020 doesn't work.  I have a bog-standard USB PC keyboard into a macbook via a dock and the insert key does nothing, not the dedicated one nor the one on the 0 key of the num keypad.  I tested with `xev` which shows no activity at all when pressing Insert.

Comment: It's not a keyboard issue, it's about the system. The `Insert` key simply does nothing, even if it's present on a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I've been succesful with fn + tab key in some apps.

Give it a try and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody is looking for the answer for MacOS Sierra (with 2017 Macbook Pro), please try: Fn+Ctrl+Enter

Answer (score 0):

For sublime text, you can use <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (oh, not zero).

Answer (score -1):

fn + tab works as the insert key in the Freeplane mind map software

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

try "fn+command+v", and let me know too :)

Comment: What do you expect Fn-Cmd-V to do?

Answer (score -3):

From an iMac running OS 10.8.5 with an extended usb keyboard using Microsoft Remote Desktop to control my PC (Win 7), I can use shift-control+0 (keypad) to send the enter key.

Comment: ‘to send the enter key’? OP is looking to simulate Insert, not Enter